# How to have a DIV with background 100% of browser height without any content in it or with less content

Tags: html, css, css-float

I have a code

```
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
   <div id="main"> Hello world.!</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

and CSS

```
body{
  background-color: black;
}

#main{
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

please help me out to have a background with 100% height. looking for jsfiddle link.

Comment: Why don't you just set the `background-color` on the body to `blue` instead?

Comment: Just make the hieght of the body to 100%. 
then your main element also 100%.

Answer (score 0):

as i have understood if you want to set the height of blue div then add this

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
}
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
}
#main {
  min-height: 100%; /** set height 100% if content is smaller **/
  height: auto; /** if the content is larger than **/
}
#main {
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="main">Hello world.!
</div>
```

Comment: This code is not dynamic and fails when the content is higher than the window height. http://jsfiddle.net/tk6hvzs4/

Answer (score 0):

```
.center-element {
    min-height: 100%;
    min-height: 50vh;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    -ms-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In CSS3 you can use vh wich stands for viewport height. i.e. 100 vh means 100% of viewport height.

height: 100vh;

Answer (score 0):

I would definitely recommend you to look at this post: [Make div 100% height of browser window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1575141/make-div-100-height-of-browser-window/16837667#16837667)

Here it is explained not just how to do it, but also the difference between `100%` and `100vh`.

Really good for extra knowledge :-)